# Combobox control for ASP.Net 2.0 (Visual Studio 2005)

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I need a ComboBox control for my website which I'm developing in Visual Studio 2005.

I have tried installing AjaxControlToolkit, but it does not contain this control.

If unable to find a free ComboBox control, I would like to emulate its functionality, where I should be able to type a search string in a textbox and matching item should be displayed in the DropDownList (without having to click on a button).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an ajax call(or you have a lot of items in your list and want an ajaxcall) you could use autocomplete extender from ajax toolkit.

Check out this link for more info : [AutoCompleteExtender](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/munnamax/AutocompleteExtender08062007113854AM/AutocompleteExtender.aspx)

The only downside would be that the user has to type something in the field before he gets a dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for you response Kristof. I have never used an ajax call before. My website is an ASP.NET WebSite. Won't I need an ASP.NET AJAX-Enabled WebSite for this?

Comment: The way we did it was just using a asmx webservice. You should be able to add one by selecting Add new item => Web => Web Service. I think all ASP.NET Website will support this.

Answer (score 0):

You require AjaxAutoComplete
Hope these link could help:
[AutoComplete Demo](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)
[AjaxAutoCompleter](http://www.noupe.com/javascript/most-wanted-ajax-techniques-50-ajax-examples-and-tutorials.html)

Another way out is:

What you can do is put the dropdownList in an update panel. And on key pressEvent Search the List.